# how to develop two(or multi) screens with UITableView and switch between them using swipe and UISegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uiscrollview

[Here is my screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh9wqkipkwllz24/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-12%20at%205.13.48%20pm.png?dl=0)

i am newbie for iOS development and wondered a lot for this task. i would like to ask in my work project there is **UISegmentcontrol** there is 6 segments and i had make them as scrollable and one single table view is there for every segment tap index pass to the tabl view's row and relod the table.i want to do like user can swipe on table view and along with segments change.
simply want to swipe to change table view and along with segment change.and individually segments are also scrollable itself which are already done.
**e.g** same as iOS notification centre.

Thanks in advance....Please help me for this task.

here is some code of segment control which i had developed for scrolling segments

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
UIScrollView * scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 76, 355, 29)];
self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(-18, 0, 820, 29);
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width,                     self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height -1);
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}
-(void)fillJournals
{
[journals removeAllObjects];
NSString *segmentName = [self.segmentedControl     titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
[journals addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",segmentName,i+1]];
}
}
-(IBAction)categoryDidChange:(id)sender
{
[self fillJournals];
[self.payTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to show a different TableView for each selected Segment?

Comment: thanx for imidiate reply,actually no mam i want to reuse table view just user can swipe table view along with  segment.simple like iphone notification center

Comment: So you only want one table with multiple segments?

Comment: Apple's notifaction view, has segment control with UITableView having swipeGesture implemented for changing views. That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you Richa but i am not exactly getting what is the right way to do or in other term how to integrate that segment control with table view that can swipe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContainerViewController` and add Gesture to TableView.on swipe just change viewcontroller

let me know if it is useful for you..

Solution 2:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1; 
}
```

by using page you can reload table with respective array

Comment: Sir tank u so much for reply but i am reusing the table view want to swipe table view along segment also.

Comment: set tag to each Segment Control and maintain arrays accordingly.

Comment: Yes sir that already done but its not work for swipe or scrolling